# Jcrop with backbone/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jcrop

I am working with jquery and I want to implement Jcrop for my project. But in all the examples I see, it is implemented in php. I am not so good at php. Can someone help me out in how to use Jcrop with JQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: so...what server framework are you using? what have you tried? more info?

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your reply. I am using ruby and backbone.js along with jquery. The problem that I am facing is.... when I select any image and select a section of that image, I am not able to crop it using the crop button.

Comment: Do you know how to manipulate images, specifically crop them, in ruby? if not, you may want to do a tutorial on that before attempting to use jCrop.

Comment: Whenever I try to add jcrop to any image, the image automatically beccomes very small in size. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think backbone.js has anything to do with it unless you're uploading images with it. What you do is use Jcrop to set the crop parameters (x,y, w,h) etc and send that to the server along with the image, the server then crops the image based on that parameter.

Comment: Whenever I try to add jcrop to any image, the image automatically beccomes very small in size. Why is that so?